# HTML5 Video Shows a black screen on load

Tags: javascript, android, html, video

I was trying to load a video using HTML5 and angularJS. But the video is showing a black screen initially and then starts playing. It only occurs in the Android Chrome browser.

I have tried the poster image, and checked the readyState of the video (called the play function only after getting the readyState value 4). But the initial black screen issue has not been fixed.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="load-image"></div>
<div class="video-poster" style="display: none;">
    <video id="video_intro" height="413" width="595" src="assets/video/video.mp4" poster="assets/images/mobile/image.png"></video>
</div>
```

And my Javascript code:

```
myVideo.load();
$('.fireneuron-button, .animate-button').click(function () {
    var myVar = setInterval(function () {
        var ready = myVideo.readyState;
        if (ready == 4) {
            myVideo.play();
            clearInterval(myVar);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.